# Finding memory leak in visual studio 2008 using c++

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I took over a big project written in c++ using visual studio 2008.   The application keeps crashing and when I look at the task manager in windows, it shows the application taken almost all the memory.   What application do people recommend to find memory leaks in c++ on windows platform?

I found some posts talking about using the visual leak in 2008 but not very effective.

Any ideas trying to find a needle in a haystack?

Thanks
-Dimitry

Comment: It's not always a needle.  Sometimes it's much more obvious than that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good Valgrind substitute for Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows)

Comment: Thanks for the info.   I tried visual leak detector but I cannot get it to show me anything.   I have a program that does not exit.   Visual leak detector says that it displays information once the program exits.   Any ideas how to see the memory leaks using this application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [UMDH.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268343), capture successive snapshots and then use umdh again to compare them.  This should give you the callstack of the owner(s) of your memory increase between the two snapshots.

Comment: Did you find umdh more helpful than visual leak detector?

Comment: I cannot say, I've never used the Visual leak detector - sorry.